# How to choose suitable battery that will supply enough current?

Tags: batteries, dc-motor, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm looking for a light-weight 12v battery that will drive 4 DC motors for few seconds burst at stall current (1.4 Amp each; according to datasheet).

How do I know which battery will supply enough current?

Comment: Do you know what kind of battery you want to use?  i.e. rechargeable, non-rechargeable?  So total current is 4 * 1.4 = 5.6A?  Do you have a link for the datasheet?

Comment: How many times do you want to do this from one set/charge of your battery?  Do you have a space or a money budget.  Using big expensive super-caps may let you use a tiny battery. If weight is your limit the Lithium technology batteries are usually in the lead, some camera batteries are pretty common and in series may be able to do what you want.

Comment: @tcrosley, yes 5.6A would be great but even 4A could be enough (actually I'll take the highest I can get :)). Charging is not a requirement... [datasheet](http://datasheet.octopart.com/FK-260SA-14280-Mabuchi-datasheet-15250215.pdf) of motor.

KalleMP, Budget is up to $150. There's no space limitation but with weight, the lightest it can get the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a battery out there that's directly 12V on its output (not counting chaining together lots of AAs and such). You might want to look into a battery like this [11.1V 2100mAh LiPo](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004UZD4Q8).

The maximum continuous current draw is the C rating * capacity. In this case, 2C * 2100mAh = 42 Amps, well above what your requirement is.

EDIT: Also keep in mind that charging LiPos requires a special charger. Don't use a charger that isn't specifically for LiPos, you could cause an explosion and fire!

Comment: There are a lot of batteries that are rated at 12V output.  traditional dry cells, alkaline and wet cells have 1.5V and 2.0V potentials that can be stacked to get 12V nominal.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a typical LiPo cell's voltage is 3.7v so 11.1v are from 3 cells. Good direction, I think I'll use 2 small 7.8v batteries for a total of 15.6v. [This one](http://www.atomikrc.com/collections/venom-lipo-batteries/products/venom-20c-2s-430mah-7-4-lipo-battery-with-jst-plug-x2-packs) looks good for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at three types of 12v batteries.  Non-rechargeable [lantern batteries](http://www.batteriesplus.com/product_search/25689-EVR732-12-Volt-Electronics-Battery.aspx), [sealed lead acid batteries](http://www.batteryspace.com/sealedleadacidbattery12v08ahs.aspx), and [Lithium LiFePO4](http://www.batteryspace.com/customizelifepo418650battery128v1350mah4sflat162wh4aratewith55x21mmmalebarrelconnectorandpcb.aspx).

The lantern battery is cheap ($10), requires no charger, but you would occasionally have to replace it, plus it's rather heavy (2.5 pounds).  Not a good choice.

The SLA battery has a maximum discharge rate of 8 A for 5 seconds, which fits your requirements, weighs 12 oz, and costs $20.  Plus you'll need a charger.

The Lithium battery weighs half as much (6 oz), but only has a mximum discharge rate of 4A and costs more ($38).

I think your best bet is the [SLA battery](http://www.batteryspace.com/sealedleadacidbattery12v08ahs.aspx).  Note this is a real 12v batteery, not an 11.1v one.

[image]